# Storing Arabic Numbers in variable in correct format

Tags: c#, oracle, unicode

I am having a weird issue of storing Arabic numerals in Oracle. After investigation I found that C# is storing Arabic digits, ۱ to ۱۰ properly and transforming them into '?' character. How do I sort this thing out?

**Code**

```
sb_title = "ھیلو۱۲۳";
query = "INSERT INTO MyTABLE(SB_TITLE)VALUES('"+sb_title+"');
OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand(query, this.myConnection);
affectedRows = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After thorough debugging what I found that variable does not temper the data but somewhere insertion mess the data. **SB_TITLE** is of type NVARCHAR

**Oracle Connection String**

```
sConnectionString = "User Id=xx;Password=xx;Data Source=XE";
```

**Oracle Version**

10g Express Edition

Comment: Command Prompt doesn't opt the Arabic font.

Comment: Please show some code. It's impossible to answer in its current form.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I have a simple string variable storing text like **حای۱۲۳**, What it does that it converts numerics like '۱','۲'،'۳' into '?' character. I tried this(http://stackoverflow.com/a/14560518/275002) it did not work either

Comment: C# fully supports UTF8 strings, it does not "change" your text. Look into other points of failure, like how you display them.

Comment: @Volatil3: That's just not happening. And that's why I am asking for code.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth code added.

Comment: what is your nchar character set? (select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET')

Comment: It was UTF16. Actually I found the reason of it. I am adding answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is weird. Oracle Driver was dealing Arabic text as a non Unicode text but for numerals it needed actually unicode value. In my connection string I did not mention **Unicode=True**. What all I did that that I changed:

```
sConnectionString = "User Id=xx;Password=xx;Data Source=XE";
```

to

```
sConnectionString = "User Id=xx;Password=xx;Data Source=XE;Unicode=True";
```

And it worked like charm