# convert unicode(hex) to string in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, casting

Is there any approach to convert Unicode like "U+4E0B" to its equivalent character?

Ex- {\U+FF8D\U+FF9E\U+FF9D\U+FF84\U+FF9E\U+FF97\U+FF72\U+FF9D - \U+4E0B}

any type of help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a Unicode character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303257/how-to-decode-a-unicode-character-in-a-string)

Comment: this may also help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184190/unicode-to-string-conversion-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Fuzzybear They are both questions with bad answers, and the format is different. The first one uses `\u00f6` instead of `\u+00f6`.

Comment: Try :System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Answer (score 3):

Simple way is using a regex + `Regex.Replace()` with delegate:

```
string str = @"\U+FF8D\U+FF9E\U+FF9D\U+FF84\U+FF9E\U+FF97\U+FF72\U+FF9D - \U+4E0BFooBar";

var rx = new Regex(@"\\U\+([0-9A-F]{4})");

string str2 = rx.Replace(str, m =>
{
    ushort u = Convert.ToUInt16(m.Groups[1].Value, 16);
    return ((char)u).ToString();
});
```

Unclear if you want to be case insensitive (so that `\u+ff9e` is valid), then use:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\\[Uu]\+([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})");
```