# VB6 to VB.NET code conversion string problem

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I had a program with code conversion VB6 (on WinXP 32bit) which sends command to RS232 radio modem.
I rewrite the code into VB.NET (WinX 64bit) but the output string to serial port is different.
For example:

VB6 code:

```
Chr$(193)
```

Output is:

[image: VB6output]

VB.NET code:

```
Convert.ToChar(193)
```

Output is:

[image: VB.Netoutput]

I think this has something to do with character tables but cannot find any solution
Thanks for any info

Comment: How are you getting from `Convert.ToChar(193)` to the output you show for that? Is it necessary to use a string between 193 and the output?

Comment: Mmm, If I remember correctly Chr$() transforms to ASCII, and Convert.ToChar() does to UNICODE ...

Comment: If you need to send `&HC1` to the port, then send `&HC1`.

Comment: @Andrew Morton instead to send it to serial i write to file, and yes i need the whole ascii table (0..255)

Comment: @GKS You can write bytes to a file, it doesn't have to be a string.

Comment: @GSerg don't know how excatly the communicarion is working, the original code sends string to serial. i'll try to send it as byte, the &HC1 was an example, the whole command can be tenths of characters

Comment: What kind of code is doing the actual sending in VB6?

Comment: The Strings class/module in VB.NET also has Chr and ChrW - why do you feel the need to reproduce this?

Answer (score -1):

According to this [link from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tochar?view=net-6.0), `Convert.toChar(...)` does this:

> Converts the value of the specified object to a Unicode character.

My guess is you're getting a unicode, since instead of `C1`, you're getting `C3 81` (Unicode can take [1-4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290182/how-many-bytes-does-one-unicode-character-take) per char).  Perhaps something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184190/unicode-to-string-conversion-in-c-sharp) would help:

> `((char)0x00C1).ToString();`